# Como calcular a distancia entre X e Y com pontos de Interseção

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem a cima eu tenho mapeada as posições de separação dentro do armazém onde eu trabalho. 
Eu preciso calcular a distancia que a pessoa que esta separando percorre dentro do armazém.
Por exemplo se a pessoa esta separando na posição 1AF-001-10  e se desloca ate a posição 1AD-013-10 se eu calcular apenas X e Y ele vai calcular em linha reta porem vai estar errado eu preciso que ele passe pelos pontos de interseção ai esta o problema.
não sei como vou fazer para ele entender quais pontos ele precisa pegar para calcular a rota certa quando ele sai das ruas que ele estava searando.
eu coloquei os pontos de interseção que seriam essas ligações... e da certinho
só não consegui raciocinar como eu faço para ele entender quais pontos ele precisa pegar.
Por exemplo nesse caso a cima ele deveria calcular da seguinte maneira:

```
    De           Para
1AF-001-10 || 1AD-013-10 = soma(valor1,valor2,valor3)
```

Ou seja :

```
   De            Para
1AF-001-10  || interseçãoE = valor1

    De            Para
interseçãoE || interseçãoD = valor2

    De            Para
interseçãoD || 1AD-013-10 = valor3
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma resposta breve que vai exigir certa pesquisa por parte do AP.

Modele seu problema como um grafo e aplique o [algoritmo A*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_A*). Os nós dos seu grafo são suas posições (1AF...). Cada aresta do seu grafo é a ligação existente entre duas localizações. Se não existir ligação, significa que a posição X não é conectada com a posição Y. A aresta carregará também a informação da distância entre cada nó.

No momento que você tiver esse grafo montado, basta implementar um algoritmo de menor caminho (indiquei o A*, mas pode ser o [Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra) puro) e passar o nó inicial e final como parâmetros. O algoritmo devolverá o menor caminho entre duas localizações, passando por todas as posições intermediárias.

Como eu disse, vai exigir um esforço de pesquisa inicial, mas tem tanto exemplo de grafo na Internet e tanto tutorial que valerá a pena, pois resolverá o problem em definitivo.

Comment: Olá, bom dia... primeiramente obrigado pela resposta, o problema é que não tenho acesso a todas ferramentas em nosso banco e tem coisas como esse que vc sugerio queeu nao tenho acesso a fazer, só conseigo fazer select e algumas funções isso dificulta bastante

Comment: Se você tem acesso ao banco para dar select, nada impede você de criar um pequeno programa que consulta esse banco, cria o grafo e aplica o algoritmo.

Comment: O colega cantoni tem toda a razão. Se você tem os De-Para individuais e a distância entre cada um, você consegue pegar os dados e construir tal programa. Infelizmente, vai precisar estudar um pouco as referências que ele passou. Mas um problema que você certamente vai ter é que fazer esse cálculo a cada consulta pode se tornar computacionalmente inviável (principalmente se ocorrem muitas consultas). Supondo que as localidades não mudem (porque são fixas no armazém), o ideal seria você pré-calcular as rotas possíveis e armazená-las em uma outra tabela. Aí a sua consulta fica trivial. :)

Comment: Poxa agora me senti um burro com vocês falando que é fácil kkkkk. Vou começar a pesquisar por que sou iniciante em sql. mas muito obrigado pelas dicas, vou ver o que eu consigo fazer

Comment: @ArielGonçalves, seu desafio não vai ser no SQL, mas em programar isso em alguma linguagem. Existe muito suporte na Internet. Quando eu disse que não é complicado, é do meu ponto de vista. Entendo completamente a sua dificuldade, mas posso afirmar que se você persistir, você conseguirá exatamente o que quer e com várias coisas a mais que você vai pensando no meio do caminho. Se você gosta de algoritmos, é um ótimo caminho a trilhar. Uma dica: Já existem frameworks e bibliotecas prontas de grafo. Monte o grafo com informacoes do banco de dados e escolha o algoritmo.